# How can I do speaker identification (diarization) with microsoft speech to text without previous voice enrollment?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform

In my application, I need to record a conversation between people and there's no room in the physical workflow to take a 20 second sample of each person's voice for the purpose of training the recognizer, nor to ask each person to read a canned passphrase for training. But without doing that, as far as I can tell, there's no way to get speaker identification.

Is there any way to just record, say, 5 people speaking and have the recognizer automatically classify returned text as belonging to one of the 5 distinct people, without previous training?

(For what it's worth, IBM Watson can do this, although it doesn't do it very accurately, in my testing.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right then [Conversation Transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/conversation-transcription) should be a solution for your scenario, as it will show the speakers as `Speaker[x]` and iterate for each new speaker, if you don't generate user profiles beforehand.

> User voice samples are optional. Without this input, the transcription
> will show different speakers, but shown as "Speaker1", "Speaker2",
> etc. instead of recognizing as pre-enrolled specific speaker names.

You can get started with the real-time conversation transcription [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription).

Comment: Hi @Ali Heikal , May I know how to pass user voice profile to get exact speaker identification?

Comment: It depends on the case, if you are talking about Speaker Recognition maybe something like `curl --location --request POST 'INSERT_ENDPOINT_HERE/speaker-recognition/verification/text-dependent/profiles/INSERT_PROFILE_ID_HERE:verify?api-version=2021-09-05' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: INSERT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY_HERE' \
--header 'Content-Type: audio/wav' \
--data-binary @'INSERT_FILE_PATH_HERE'` and you can find more examples in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-speaker-recognition?tabs=script&pivots=programming-language-rest)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Conversation Transcription which is in Preview, now targeting to microphone array device. So the input recording should be recorded by a microphone array. If your recordings are from common microphone, it may not work and you need special configuration. You can also try [Batch diarization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription#speaker-separation-diarization) which support offline transcription with diarizing 2 speakers for now, it will support 2+ speaker very soon, probably in this month.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REST API then it will be helpful.
You can use [batch transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) with "diarizationEnabled" property as true and you will need to use only 1 channel and you will also need to give minimum and maximum number of speakers ( it can identify up to 36 speakers ). also use 3.1 version insted of 3.0 of REST API

here in how I used it:

```
url = f'{<speech_resourse_endpoint>}/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions'
data = {
    'displayName': 'name that you would like for transcription',
    "description": "Description of your task",
    'locale': 'en-US',
    'contentUrls': [<audio_url>],
    'properties': {
        'diarizationEnabled': True,
        'wordLevelTimestampsEnabled': True,
        "displayFormWordLevelTimestampsEnabled": True,
        "channels": [0],
        "diarization": {
          "speakers": {
            "minCount": 1,
            "maxCount": 20
          }
        }
        
    },
    "languageIdentification": {
        "candidateLocales": ["en-US","en-CA"],
    },
    "customProperties": {}
}

# intializer of transcription process
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

# Get the URL of the transcription status and output files  
self_url = response.json()['self']  
print(self_url)
files_url = response.json()['links']['files']

status = ""  
while status != "Succeeded":  
    # Send a GET request to get the transcription status  
    response = requests.get(self_url, headers=headers)  
    status = response.json()['status']
    print(f"Transcription status: {status}")  
    time.sleep(2)

#request to access list of files
response = requests.get(files_url, headers=headers)

response_json = response.json()

file_url = response_json["values"][0]["links"]["contentUrl"]
print(f"file_url = {file_url}")
```

Go to printed 'file_url' and in field called 'recognizedPhrases' you will see phrases with speaker identified

sample output :

```
{


"source": "-----",
  "timestamp": "2023-10-16T18:13:54Z",
  "durationInTicks": 4697600000,
  "duration": "PT7M49.76S",
  "combinedRecognizedPhrases": [
    {
      "channel": 0,
      "lexical": "....whole transcription....",
      "itn": ".....whole transcription....",
      "display": ".....whole transcription...."
    }
  ],
  "recognizedPhrases": [
    {
      "recognitionStatus": "Success",
      "channel": 0,
      "speaker": 1,
      "offset": "PT0.72S",
      "duration": "PT19.28S",
      "offsetInTicks": 7200000.0,
      "durationInTicks": 192800000.0,
      "nBest": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.27163595,
          "lexical": "----phrash----",
          "itn": "-----phrase---",
          "maskedITN": "-----phrase----",
          "display": "-----phrase----"
    },...]
```